# Delta live tables - Slowly changing dimensions

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, scd, delta-live-tables

Is it possible to create an Slowly Changing Dimension mechanism using Delta Live Tables? I would like to implement something like this https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-scd-type-2.html

But in the DLT docs i found "Processing updates from source tables, for example, merges and deletes, is not supported. To process updates, see the APPLY CHANGES INTO command" - but
https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-cdc.html it's only for CDC, do you have any idea for SCD?

Comment: your first link is broken

Comment: @OliverAngelil They removed this notebook. It was very similar to this example: https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd-using-delta-tables-511122022e45 

Here u can find docs about merge in delta lake docs:
https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#id2

And in Databricks docs:
https://docs.databricks.com/delta/merge.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed right now DLT supports only SCD Type 1 (CDC). Support for SCD Type 2 is currently in the private preview, and should be available in near future - refer to the [Databricks Q2 public roadmap](https://databricks.com/p/webinar/productroadmapwebinar) for more details on it.  If you have solutions architect or customer success engineer in your account, ask them to include you into private preview.

Update, September 2022: SCD type 2 is generally available since June 2022: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/06/29/delta-live-tables-announces-new-capabilities-and-performance-optimizations.html

Comment: Are you familiar with the workaround example? Can it be done by using CDC or something? or should i create it using this method https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-scd-type-2.html

Comment: I know that implementation but i haven't used with DLT

Answer (score 2):

DLT is now supporting SCD Type 2 in public preview. You can learn about it and see examples in [this document](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-cdc.html?_gl=1*1ldy9zh*_gcl_aw*R0NMLjE2NTYwMjYxNDIuQ2owS0NRandudENWQmhEZEFSSXNBTUV3QUNrNHF0OVJPbjRSUEZ6SU0zS1FrOXZtamk2a1d2VEFfLVAxYmJHY1hvMnprWm5Wc19SMFVHSWFBby0tRUFMd193Y0I.&_ga=2.143897781.185930895.1657033128-1547688913.1627598437&_gac=1.149336644.1656026142.Cj0KCQjwntCVBhDdARIsAMEwACk4qt9ROn4RPFzIM3KQk9vmji6kWvTA_-P1bbGcXo2zkZnVs_R0UGIaAo--EALw_wcB)

Answer (score 1):

Merge is supported in DLT , please see the sample code below

```
mergeDF1
  .as("merge_tbl1")
  .merge(mergeDF2.as("merge_tbl2"), "merge_tbl1.key = merge_tbl2.key")
  .whenMatched("merge_tbl1.isCurrent = true AND (merge_tbl2.country <> merge_tbl1.country OR merge_tbl2.region <> merge_tbl1.region)")
  .updateExpr(Map(
    "isCurrent" -> "false",
    "endDate" -> "<date>",
  .whenNotMatched()
  .insertExpr(Map(
    "personId" -> "<personId>",
    "personName" -> "<personName>",
    "country" -> "<country>",
    "region" -> "<region>,
    "isCurrent" -> "true",
    "effectiveDate" -> "<date>",
    "endDate" -> "null"))
  .execute()
```

Comment: Your code uses Scala that isn't supported by DLT...